# python generating random integers with a certain chance of one number

Tags: python, random

How can I generate a random integer between 1 and 10 inclusive, 5 times but will have an 80% chance of one of the values being 1 once?  Is it possible?

Comment: Can you clarify: you want to generate a random number that is not entirely random but skewed to pick some number(s) more often than others?

Comment: Anything is possible when you think? What language is this. Give us more details.

Comment: @Zizouz212 - He said Python in the title, but agreed that we need more details.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, I didn't notice that. Normally, I just skip right to the question... :P

Answer (score 2):

According to the question, the random number must be generated 5 times. And each time the 80% probability of picking value '1' must be checked. In the other 20% of cases a random number between 2 and 10 is returned.

```
import random

def get_number():
    if random.random() <= 0.8:
        return 1
    else:
        return random.randint(2, 10)

for i in range(5):
    print(get_number())
```

Comment: OP said "80% chance of one of the values being 1 once".  This will, on average, produce four 1's out of every 5 trials.

Answer (score 0):

A random 80% of the time, draw a sample of four values from the range 2-10 inclusive, append 1, then shuffle.  The other 20% of the time, just draw a sample of five values from the range of values excluding 1.

```
if random.random() <= 0.8:
    result = random.sample(xrange(2,11), 4) + [1]
    random.shuffle(result)
else:
    result = random.sample(xrange(2,11), 5)
```

Note that I've assumed sampling without replacement.  If you want sampling with replacement, this would need to be revised.